# Bind GridView on the basis of Selected Value HeaderFilterFillItems

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I am using Devexpress Gridview control to bind the data and filter the headers using HeaderFilterFillItems. But when I select a particular value from dropdown it shows as "No Data to Display". what could be the cause for it?

I have attached an image, which shows that when I select ID as "184" it shows "No Data to Display" where as it should show one record.

code:

```
protected void dx_Approval_HeaderFilterFillItems(object sender, ASPxGridViewHeaderFilterEventArgs e) 
{ 
DataTable dtApprove = (DataTable)Session["ApprovalList"];
 int count = dtApprove.Rows.Count;
 HashSet<object> columnValues = new HashSet<object>();
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
 string value = (dtApprove.Rows[i][e.Column.FieldName]).ToString();
 if (!columnValues.Contains(value))
 {
     columnValues.Add((dtApprove.Rows[i][e.Column.FieldName]).ToString()); e.AddValue(value, value);
 }
 }
 }
```

[Demo pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kqij.png)

Comment: I think you have to fill and bind the grid again for the filters to work. Can you show your code ?

Comment: 'protected void dx_Approval_HeaderFilterFillItems(object sender, ASPxGridViewHeaderFilterEventArgs e) {
DataTable dtApprove = (DataTable)Session["ApprovalList"];
            int count = dtApprove.Rows.Count;
            HashSet<object> columnValues = new HashSet<object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            { string value = (dtApprove.Rows[i][e.Column.FieldName]).ToString();
                if (!columnValues.Contains(value))  { columnValues.Add((dtApprove.Rows[i][e.Column.FieldName]).ToString());  e.AddValue(value, value); } } }'